# Android Jetpack Compose(Composable) Change Theme Color Smoothly

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

Since I don't want to use the base Colors class, instead I want to use my own colors that are not used in neither buttons or text elements. So I created my own Colors class with the corresponding light and dark palette classes. Then in my composable I want to change the theme color, but using animation, this is why I used ***animateColorAsState***, but the code looks very ugly. Is there a way to animate all the colors, without defining animateColorAsState for each color separately?

Here is the result
[image]

Code for the custom color palettes

```
@Stable
class Colors(
    background: Color,
    line90DegColor: Color,
    hoursArrowColor: Color,
    secondsArrowColor: Color,
    baseColor: Color,
    lighter: Color,
    darker: Color,
    baseColorLessTransparent: Color,
    baseColorSemiTransparent: Color,
    baseColorTransparent: Color
) {
    var background by mutableStateOf(background, structuralEqualityPolicy())
        internal set

    var line90DegColor by mutableStateOf(line90DegColor, structuralEqualityPolicy())
        internal set

    // same for the rest of the colors

}

val LightColorPalette = Colors(
    background = Color(0xFFECECF3),
    line90DegColor = Color(0xFF9B9BB0),
    // same for the rest of the colors
)

val DarkColorPalette = Colors(
    background = Color(0xFF25252D),
    line90DegColor = Color(0xFF9B9BB0),
    // same for the rest of the colors
)
```

Code for the composable, where the colors are changes via ***animateColorAsState***

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 
        setContent {

            var isLightTheme by remember {
                mutableStateOf(true)
            }
            val colors = if (isLightTheme) {
                LightColorPalette
            } else {
                DarkColorPalette
            }

            // create color state for each of the theme color
            val animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Color> = tween(durationMillis = 1500)
            val background by animateColorAsState(colors.background, animationSpec)
            val line90DegColor by animateColorAsState(colors.line90DegColor, animationSpec)
            val hoursArrowColor by animateColorAsState(colors.hoursArrowColor, animationSpec)
            val secondsArrowColor by animateColorAsState(colors.secondsArrowColor, animationSpec)
            val baseColor by animateColorAsState(colors.baseColor, animationSpec)
            val lighter by animateColorAsState(colors.lighter, animationSpec)
            val darker by animateColorAsState(colors.darker, animationSpec)
            val baseColorLessTransparent by animateColorAsState(colors.baseColorLessTransparent, animationSpec)
            val baseColorSemiTransparent by animateColorAsState(colors.baseColorSemiTransparent, animationSpec)
            val baseColorTransparent by animateColorAsState(colors.baseColorTransparent, animationSpec)

            // create new Colors object that matches the current theme
            val animatedColors = Colors(
                background,
                line90DegColor,
                hoursArrowColor,
                secondsArrowColor,
                baseColor,
                lighter,
                darker,
                baseColorLessTransparent,
                baseColorSemiTransparent,
                baseColorTransparent
            )

            ClockWidget(animatedColors, hours, minutes, seconds) {
                isLightTheme = !isLightTheme
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think u can try wrapping your code to AnimationContent with `targetState = your theme` how easy way. Or you can write somethink like this:

```
@Stable
data class Colors(
    val background: Color,
    val line90DegColor: Color,
    val hoursArrowColor: Color,
    val secondsArrowColor: Color,
    val baseColor: Color,
    val lighter: Color,
    val darker: Color,
    val baseColorLessTransparent: Color,
    val baseColorSemiTransparent: Color,
    val baseColorTransparent: Color
) {
    private val animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Color> = tween(durationMillis = 1500)

    @Composable
    private fun animateColor(
        targetValue: Color,
        finishedListener: ((Color) -> Unit)? = null
    ) = animateColorAsState(targetValue = targetValue, animationSpec = animationSpec).value
    
    @Composable
    fun switch() = copy(
        background = animateColor(background),
        secondsArrowColor = animateColor(secondsArrowColor),
        lighter = animateColor(lighter),
        darker = animateColor(darker),
        //etc
    )
```

and change your variable animatedColors to

```
val animatedColors = (if (isLightTheme) LightColorPalette else DarkColorPalette).switch()
```

and i recommend you read about [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal)

Comment: Thanks I ended up using your answer together with CompositionLocalProvider as you suggested, instead of passing the colors object to all descendants of the main Composable.